# RadGrid Column Filtering issue

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

Please find my sample project in the attachment. i have also included the database script for the project

http://www.4shared.com/get/5pSvIMoX/testRadGrid.html

I'm trying to do a simple radgrid bind. i've done it with two pages.

please see default.aspx - the column filter options are showed when i click on the filter icon as i expected but in search.aspx i'm binding through a database data source then the column filtering options (contains, equals...) are not shown.

error is shown in the console.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'control' of undefined

Please let me know whats wrong with search.aspx radgrid column filtering

Comment: Doubtful anyones going to go through the hassle of signing up for an account to just dl your project. Might want to try a different host.

Comment: @KreepN no need to signup for download.